# Add or Remove class on click - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a class when you click on a box then remove the class when you click the button. But no class os added or removed.

```
var leftBox = document.getElementsByClassName("left");
var rightBox = document.getElementsByClassName("right");

function expandLeft() {
  leftBox.className = leftBox.className + "zero-width";
  rightBox.className = rightBox.className + "full-width";
}
function expandRight() {
  leftBox.className = leftBox.className + "full-width";
  rightBox.className = rightBox.className + "zero-width";
}

function originalLeft(){ 
  leftBox.removeClass(leftBox, "zero-width");
  rightBox.removeClass(rightBox, "full-width");
}

function originalRight(){ 
  leftBox.removeClass(rightBox, "full-width");
  rightBox.removeClass(leftBox, "zero-width");
}



<div class="row">
<div class="wrapper flex full-width">
<div class="form_wrapper flex full-width">
<div class="left">
<div class="form_wrapper--left" onclick="expandRight()">
<div><button id="shrink" onclick="originalLeft()">click here</button> . 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END OR RIGHT BOX --
<!-- START OR RIGHT BOX -->
<div class="right">
<div class="form_wrapper--right" onclick="expandLeft()">
<div>
<button id="shrink" onclick="originalLeft()">click here</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--- END of Right Box --->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The effect should be that when you click one box it expands left and you can click a button and it returns. Vice versa for the other side.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: We need a [mcve] to be able to understand your code and help you, otherwise it's almost impossible and you probably will get your question closed and downvoted

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggleClass()` in jQuery.

maybe this link helps:
https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", enlarge);
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", resume);

function enlarge() {
  document.getElementById("test").classList.add("enlarge");
}

function resume() {
  document.getElementById("test").classList.remove("enlarge");
}
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.enlarge {
  transform: scaleX(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>

<button id="btn">
  Resume
</button>
```